# How can I know if my minVersion is good?

Tags: android, eclipse

For example, if I put a spinner (which requires version 11) and my minVersion is 8, it will do an error, but if I go to AndroidManifest.xml, change the 11 to 8 and directly compile, it works! How can I check all the project if the minVersion is good and compatible with everything?

Comment: Your compilation will not fail, simple as that. :-)

Comment: No, if I "quickly" put my minVersion back to 8 (but it is supposed to be 11 for the spinner) the compilation actually works!! It's unbelievable

Comment: What does "quickly" mean?

Comment: @Simon I meant if I change the minVersion and just after, without opening other files, run my project.

Comment: @Mageek have you tried to change the target to 8 temporarily?

Comment: @SaifHamed Thanks but it didn't work too, but I found the solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to right click on the project > Android tools > Run lint

Answer (score 0):

If you click project -> clean... it will update and show you the errors that should be there.

It's a great tool for all the false errors and true errors ;)

Comment: How didn't it work? Spinner was added in API 1 and have methods that requires higher API. So if you dont use them, eclipse will not blame you.

Comment: If I open my layout with the spinner, edit something and save the file then only it will display the error message. It's like errors are hidden...

Comment: You have no code to show?

As you may noticed eclipse don't check for all errors after each character you type in the code. But it do check when saving, formatting and using clean.